# Reterofit not returning Response Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new to retrofit and trying to catch it up with a turorial at [Reterofit Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) but Im unable to get any response from it. I have tried debuging the app with breakpoint inside the ***onResponse*** and ***onFailure*** but im ubale to hit these breakpoints. and dont know where getting wrong.
**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;
    public static final String Base_Url = "https://api.stackexchange.com";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        //set support for toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ReteroFiller serverGet = new ReteroFiller();
        serverGet.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private class ReteroFiller extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String> implements Callback<StackOverFlowQuestions>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
            StackOverFlowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(StackOverFlowAPI.class);

            Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");
            //asynchronous call
           // call.enqueue();

            // synchronous call would be with execute, in this case you
            // would have to perform this outside the main thread
            // call.execute()

            // to cancel a running request
            // call.cancel();
            // calls can only be used once but you can easily clone them
            //Call<StackOverflowQuestions> c = call.clone();
            call.enqueue(this);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

           if(progressDialog!=null){
               progressDialog.dismiss();

           }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           if(progressDialog==null){
               progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                       "ProgressDialog",
                       "Progressing");
           }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


        }


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call, Response<StackOverFlowQuestions> response) {
            Log.i("RETERO TEST : ","Message: "+response.message()+" Body : "+response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**StackOverFlowQuestions Class**

```
public class StackOverFlowQuestions {
    List<Question> items;
}
```

**Questions Model Class:**

```
public class Question {

        String title;
        String link;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return(title);
        }
    }
```

**StackOverFlowAPI: Interface**

```
public interface StackOverFlowAPI {
    @GET("/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
    Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> loadQuestions(
            @Query("tagged") String tags
    );
}
```

Comment: where is your interface?

Comment: Works fro me. I would remove the toast  message. `call.enqueue` itself an asynchronous call. So you can remove asynctask

Comment: I ve seen some of the stuff mentioning the RestAdapter but in particular code and even at their official site there is no reference fro the particular adapter. So when to use it?

Comment: This could look strange, but please try to change this
.baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
to this
.baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com/") 
and this
 @GET("/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
to this
 @GET("2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the `asynctask` it works fine , here is my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<StackOverFlowQuestions> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        StackOverFlowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(StackOverFlowAPI.class);

        Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");

        call.enqueue(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call, Response<StackOverFlowQuestions> response) {
        Log.d("RETERO TEST : ","Message: "+response.message()+" Body : "+response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<StackOverFlowQuestions> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I used rest of your code, also I added the following gradle dependenies

```
//retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Ive tried it up as well thanks worked well. but unable to get response.body().items as its not recognizing items

Comment: it is because your model is not mapped according to your response from api

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you forgot to set `client` for your `retrofit`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()) // this is what you need!
                .build();
```